# OpenMP edge detection filter parallelism: takes longer

Tags: opencv, openmp, sobel

I would like to apply a sobel filter to a large image.

I am using OpenMP to do parallelism in order to optimise the calculation time.

After using for parallelism optimisations, I notice that it takes longer than expected. Here is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


// Computes the x component of the gradient vector
// at a given point in a image.
// returns gradient in the x direction
int xGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
    return image.at<uchar>(y-1, x-1) +
                2*image.at<uchar>(y, x-1) +
                 image.at<uchar>(y+1, x-1) -
                  image.at<uchar>(y-1, x+1) -
                   2*image.at<uchar>(y, x+1) -
                    image.at<uchar>(y+1, x+1);
}

// Computes the y component of the gradient vector
// at a given point in a image
// returns gradient in the y direction

int yGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
    return image.at<uchar>(y-1, x-1) +
                2*image.at<uchar>(y-1, x) +
                 image.at<uchar>(y-1, x+1) -
                  image.at<uchar>(y+1, x-1) -
                   2*image.at<uchar>(y+1, x) -
                    image.at<uchar>(y+1, x+1);
}




int main()
{
const clock_t begin_time = clock();
      Mat src, dst;
      int gx, gy, sum;

      // Load an image
      src = imread("/home/cgross/Downloads/pano.jpg", 0);
      dst = src.clone();
      if( !src.data )
      { return -1; }

#pragma omp parallel for private(gx, gy, sum) shared(dst)
        for(int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
                dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(gx, gy, sum) shared(dst)

        for(int y = 1; y < src.rows - 1; y++){

            for(int x = 1; x < src.cols - 1; x++){
                gx = xGradient(src, x, y);
                gy = yGradient(src, x, y);
                sum = abs(gx) + abs(gy);
                sum = sum > 255 ? 255:sum;
                sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
                dst.at<uchar>(y,x) = sum;
            }
        }

        namedWindow("final", WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow("final", dst);

        namedWindow("initial", WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow("initial", src);

std::cout << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
      waitKey();


    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the pragma (disable OpenMP), the calculation is faster (by 10 seconds), i dont see where the problem is.

Comment: Instead of using `clock()` why don't you try `omp_get_wtime()`

Comment: Unless running on Windows, using `clock()` to measure program's performance will almost always render worse timings for parallel programs and there are [countless other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[openmp]+clocks_per_sec) here that fall for the same catch.

Comment: Typically, small loops do not optimize well with OpenMP.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own Soebel, I would consider using either.

1) Built in OpenCv Function
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#sobel

2) Creating a Soebel kernel and using OpenCv filter2D() function.  Other libraries, platforms, etc, have similar functions for passing a kernel across an image and many are already optimized. For instance, iOS has something called vImage I think.

Then you can compare those times to your custom code.

You say you have a "large" image, but that doesn't mean much how many pixels are we talking about?

You can split the image up in to sections and perform the filtering on each (with a thread , etc)  then combine the sections back to make a new image. I have had good success doing that.

I would also read this:

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-resources/programming-in-opencl/image-convolution-using-opencl/